Error During APT Update
I'm getting the below errors, and not sure how to resolve.
Err:1 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease          
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0686B78420038257

W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0686B78420038257```

W: Failed to fetch https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/dists/stable/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0686B78420038257

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.


Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What version of Ubuntu are you running? Please run lsb_release -a and Edit your question to include this information.
